# Why does this Navigation Drawer not open?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make a Navigation Drawer, I'm reading a lot of guides on how to do this and I think it should work now, but the Drawer does not open when I click on the title (when I manually try to open it, then the icon will get smaller, but still no menu appears). Also, I'm not getting any errors or exception, so I think I might be missing something which I cannot figure out myself. 
This is the code of my `BaseActivity` (the drawer activity which gets extended by my `MainActivity`):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ListView drawerList;
    private String[] drawerListEntries;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        drawerListEntries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_items);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) 
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.hello_world);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerListEntries));



        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long arg3) {
                String selectedValue = (String) drawerList.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_user).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

This is my `activity_base.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my `drawer_list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" 
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:textColor="@color/belize_hole"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light">
    </TextView>



</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my `MainActivity.java` which extends `BaseActivity`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Anyone who can see the problem?

Comment: but you are overriding your contentview with "R.layout.activity_home". what if you'll comment `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);`?

Comment: @nikis Thanks a lot, it works now. But what I don't understand is: what the about the Layout of the the MainActivity itself and any other activity which extends the BaseActivity? Because I want the navigation drawer on almost all activities. And put your answer in a question so I can accept your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding content view from `BaseActivity` by calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` in `HomeActivity`.

I suggest you to switch fragments instead of activities with Navigation Drawer, it's the best way. So you will have one hosting activity with Navigation Drawer and you'll switch only views inside FrameLayout, for instance. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html